# Convert code from actionscript to python

Tags: python, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to convert a project from actionscript to python. Here is the actionscript code:

```
private static function parseSTUFF(_arg1):String{
            var _local4:String;
            var _local5:int;
            var _local2 = "";
            var _local3:int;
            while (_local3 < _arg1.length) {
                _local4 = _arg1.substr(_local3, 1);
                _local5 = _local4.charCodeAt(0);
                if ((((_local5 >= 48)) && ((_local5 <= 57)))){
                    _local4 = String((int(_local4) ^ 1));
                };
                _local2 = (_local2 + _local4);
                _local3++;
            };
            return (_local2);
        }
```

and here is my attemp in python

```
local4=''
local5=0
local2=''
local3 = 0
while (local3<len(arg1)):
  local4 = arg1[1:]
  local5 = int(local4[0].encode("hex"))
  if ((((local5 >= 48)) and ((local5 <= 57)))):
    local4 = str((int(local4) ^ 1))
  local2 = (local2 + local4)
  local3 = local3+1

print local2
```

For some unknown reason, my python code does not give the same value.
What I am doing wrong? Someone could help me?

Comment: `local5 = ord(local4[0]);`

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what your code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it which you want?

```
local4=''
local5=0
local2=''
local3 = 0


while (local3<len(arg1)):
  local4 = arg1[local3:local3+1]
  local5 = ord(local4[0])
  if ((((local5 >= 48)) and ((local5 <= 57)))):
    local4 = str((int(local4) ^ 1))
  local2 = (local2 + local4)
  local3 = local3+1

print local2
```